# Page still refreshes after wrapping the repeater in an update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I've two SqlDataSources and two Repeaters, each repeater contains one hyperlink (i also tried using web server button and anchors).

The hyperlinks fetch from the database some values and in the NavigationUrl property I use a `string.Format` method to create a parameterized url, to pass for the browser, then second repeater is populated according to the value passed in the url which is originally passed by the first repeater's hyperlink

this is my sample code : https://gist.github.com/726213

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="Scrptmanagr"  runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updtpanl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [arrange_by_id], [arrange_by] FROM [arrange_by]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("{0}?SortingType={1}",Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, Eval("arrange_by_id"))%>' runat="server"><%# Eval("arrange_by") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                |
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [alphabet_id],[arrange_by_id], [value] FROM [alphabet] WHERE ([arrange_by_id] = @arrange_by_id)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="arrange_by_id" QueryStringField="SortingType" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink  ID="hyper1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("{0}?SortingType={1}&SortBy={2}",Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, Eval("arrange_by_id"),Eval("value"))%>'><%# Eval("value")%></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                |
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now! everytime I click any of the hyperlinks it causes a full post back and refreshes the page! Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure an `<asp:HyperLink>` isn't going to get you a partial update, it renders to HTML as an `<a href="..">` tag. You'll need a control that actually causes a postback, an `<asp:Button>` or `<asp:LinkButton>`.

Comment: Yh, unfortunately I've tried using asp.net buttons and still the same!
  <asp:Button runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# string.Format("{0}?SortingType={1}",Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, Eval("arrange_by_id"))%>' Text='<%# Eval("arrange_by") %>'></asp:Button>

Comment: Don't put a PostBackUrl in there! You are forcing it to NOT post back to your current page, and thus it can't be wrapped up into a partial update. Just do an `<asp:Button>` with an OnClick event! Alternatively, maybe you'd be better off just using an `iframe` rather than an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`, if you're wedded to the approach of having everything in the URL?

Comment: I'm not wedded to any approach, it just what came up to my mind!
if you have any suggestions to pass a parameter to the url just share it! I hope I could learn better approaches!

Comment: ok I'm kinda stuck here! linkbutton or button can't have an OnClick event when it's inside a repeater! instead you use the CommandArgument property and search for it in the itemCommand event of the repeater!....now how is that possible to let the onClick event or whatever = <%# string.Format("{0}?SortingType={1}",Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath, Eval("arrange_by_id"))%>' Text='<%# Eval("arrange_by") %>!!

Comment: Put the identifier of the individual data item in the `Button`'s `CommandArgument`. If you have multiple buttons in each `Repeater` item, put something in each `Button`'s `CommandName` so you know which `Button` is which. Then catch the `Repeater`'s `ItemCommand` event to do your work.

Comment: Sorry! could you provide a sample code to illustrate your comment ? and it's probably just one button in a repeater!

Comment: Here's a writeup with good sample code: http://dotnetrush.blogspot.com/2006/12/using-repeater-itemcommand.html

Comment: Ok, this example gives every item a value so when it's click it returns it so you could get a control over it from the database or an array!...but my situation is that I want to put this format.string() method in the address bar so I could pass the querystring!...If i'm not clear plz tell me what you need to know to make it more clear!

Comment: If you want to go to a new URL in the querystring, you can't do a a partial page update. It's as simple as that. That's not how partial page updates work. They involve staying on the same page, same URL, and updating part of the page's content.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help me!...I'm just new and sometimes I implement the resources and options provided by the framework the wrong way..since I didn't actually find any good implementation example for my weired or very specific needs!...could you please check my comment on Nick's answer, I think the picture is becoming more clear now!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly any value you want to pass back don't use query strings, its the same page.
Place the content in hidden field or the buttons CommandArgument

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFieldName" Value='<%# Eval("columnName") %>' runat="server" />
```

then on the comand behind

```
    protected void rptName_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName.Equals("ButtonCommandName"))
        {
            RepeaterItem objItem = e.Item;
            var objFieldValue = (HiddenField)objItem.FindControl("hdnFieldName"); 
        }
    }
```

And remember to set the update panel Mode="conditional' this will cause the updatepanel to only update when one of the following occurs:

1) If a control within the updatepanel causes a postback e.g. asp.net button.

2) If a trigger on the updatepanel occurs (about triggers: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

3) Finally if the "Update()" method is called

Otherwise, it won't update and refresh. When its set to always, any postback outside the updatepanel or another updatepanel can trigger the updatepanel to refresh.

Comment: Ok nick, that makes sense..so I'll pass the value for the second repeater internally not through a querystring (sorry! I got the use of the queryStrings wrong :S)..but as you see I want to have a special kind of sorting, so how can I make a page sorted by Name for example "bookmarkable" ?
one other thing! I don't get what's the code if I want to use the commandArgument and what's the code used for for the second repeater's datasource ?! since it won't let me choose specify which control to use -i'm not sure what to select as the source for my where parameter value, or if am doing it all wrong-